# Find all exact occurrences of multiple strings in R

Tags: r, filter, grepl

I have a large data frame that contains causes of death from 2000 to 2020. It has many of the major causes of death broken into subgroups but I only want the main groups. For example cancers are "malignant neoplasms" but there are "malignant neoplasms of the lungs" "... of the kidneys" etc. All I want is "malignant neoplasms" so that I am not double counting deaths. I have been trying grepl but that doesn't seem to be working yet. Here is what I was working on:

```
keyword.list <- list("Malignant neoplasms [C00-C97]",
                 "Diabetes mellitus [E10-E14]",
                 "Alzheimer's disease [G30]",
                 "Major cardiovascular diseases [I00-I78]",
                 "Cerebrovascular diseases [I60-I69]",
                 "Influenza and pneumonia [J09-J18]",
                 "Chronic lower respiratory diseases [J40-J47]",
                 "Nephritis, nephrotic syndrome and nephrosis [N00-N07, N17-N19, N25-N27]",
                 "Accidents (unintentional injuries) [V01-X59, Y85-Y86]")
deaths2 <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(keyword.list)){
   deaths2 <- filter(deaths, grepl(i, `Cause of death (ICD-10)`))
}
```

So how do I make a new dataframe that contains all the rows that have the nine causes of death listed above? Then I can do some more filtering and make a chart

[image: Data frame example]

Comment: If you're looking for strict equality, why not use `filter(deaths, i == "Cause of death (ICD-10)")`?

Comment: Yes, if you are looking for exact match you should use `==` instead of `grepl`. How about `deaths2 <- subset(deaths, \`Cause of death (ICD-10)\` %in% unlist(keyword.list))` ?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Ronak Shah! That worked perfectly

```
deaths2<- subset(deaths, `Cause of death (ICD-10)` %in% unlist(keyword.list))
```